# Get My Web App Base URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

How could I get my web App URL in Node.js? I mean if my site base url is http://localhost:8080/MyApp How could I get it?

Thanks,

Comment: thru a web browser? What do you mean by how could I get it?

Comment: No I'm using node.js. So I need it on server side

Comment: you mean you want to make an http request from node? look at the http library and http.req

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You must connect 'url' module

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url') ;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var hostname = req.headers.host; // hostname = 'localhost:8080'
  var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname; // pathname = '/MyApp'
  console.log('http://' + hostname + pathname);

  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

UPD:

In Node.js v8 url module get new API for working with URLs. See [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html):

> Note: While the Legacy API has not been deprecated, it is maintained solely for backwards compatibility with existing applications. New application code should use the WHATWG API.

Comment: req.headers can be spoofed by the user making the request, be careful with trusting it.

Answer (score 17):

To get the url like: http://localhost:8080/MyApp

we should use:-

```
req.protocol+"://"+req.headers.host
```

Answer (score 2):

For getting url details in your node apps. You have to use URL module. URL module will split your web address into readable parts

Following I have given the code

```
var url = require('url');
var adr = 'http://localhost:8080/default.htm?year=2017&month=february';
var q = url.parse(adr, true);

console.log(q.host); //returns 'localhost:8080'
console.log(q.pathname); //returns '/default.htm'
console.log(q.search); //returns '?year=2017&month=february'

var qdata = q.query; //returns an object: { year: 2017, month: 'february' }
console.log(qdata.month); //returns 'february'`enter code here`
```

To learn more about URL module you can visit 
https://nodejs.org/api/url.html

Comment: this is not a solution to get base url of the application- I have tried but failed