# NodeJS 12.6.0 can't see the URL output from a request

Tags: node.js

I'm testing a local HTTP server in NodeJS. The server snippet is pasted bellow. I'm accessing the server using **http://localhost:5500**. Why is the url parser returning null properties? What am I missing?

*It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.*

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;
let decoder = new StringDecoder('utf-8');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    /* Set header */
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    /* Local variables */
    let buffer = '';

    /* Check for incoming request */
    req.on('data', (data) => {
        buffer += decoder.write(data);
    });

    /* Check for complete request */
    req.on('end', () => {
        buffer += decoder.end();

        /* Feedback about req */
        //console.log(buffer);

        /* Feedback URL */
        //let my_url = url.parse(req.url, true);
        console.log(url.parse(req.url));

        /* End res */
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: 'OK' }));
    });

}).listen(5500);

server.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
});
```

Output:

```
    Url {protocol: null, slashes: null, auth: null, host: null, port: null, …}
index.js:28
auth:null
hash:null
host:null
hostname:null
href:"/"
path:"/"
pathname:"/"
port:null
protocol:null
query:null
search:null
slashes:null
__proto__:Object {parse: , format: , resolve: , …}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure why the URL isn’t showing. But here’s a way to get the base URL: [Get My Web App Base URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251805/get-my-web-app-base-url-in-javascript)